# Skipping unresponsive host using net/http

Tags: ruby

I am using net/http to send a bunch of request to some internal IP addresses.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
  File.open("internalcorpIPs", "r") do |f|
    f.each_line do |line|
      puts line
      res = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(line))
      getCode = res.code
    end
  end
```

I'm strictly just making a request to http://IP and https://IP but it seems like this method only works if every single IP/line address is live. How do I skip IP addresses with no webserver (or 80/443 ports)?

Is it possible to make it read the line, and move on to the next if no response code was returned?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens you request a non-live IP? Does it just hang or does it throw a error?

Comment: It just hangs. I was hoping it'd throw an error so I can catch it and ignore it but that's not the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply wrap your request in `begin/rescue` block like this:

```
  File.open("internalcorpIPs", "r") do |f|
    f.each_line do |line|
      puts line
      begin
        # strip and encode uri from the file
        uri = URI.parse(URI.encode(line.strip))
        res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
        getCode = res.code
      rescue Timeout::Error => e
        puts e
        false
      end
    end
  end
```

But you will wait for 60 seconds at least before going in timeout, so I suggest to decrease the timeout. Furthermore, you could introduce an additional guard clause to check if the uri contains the scheme `http://` or `https://`, otherwise raise an exception (or something else).

```
require 'net/http'

File.open("internalcorpIPs", "r") do |f|
  f.each do |line|
    puts line

    begin
      # strip and encode uri from the file
      uri = URI.parse(URI.encode(line.strip))

      # if uri misses the schema (http:// or https://) -> raise error
      raise URI::Error, "uri #{uri} miss the scheme" unless uri.scheme

      http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
      http.open_timeout = 2 # seconds
      http.read_timeout = 2 # seconds

      http.start do |conn|
         response = conn.request_get(path = '/')
         puts response.code
      end
    rescue Timeout::Error, URI::Error, SocketError => e
      puts e
      false
    end
  end
end
```

Additional notes:

**Open Timeout**

> Number of seconds to wait for the connection to open. Any number may be used, including Floats for fractional seconds. If the HTTP object cannot open a connection in this many seconds, it raises a Net::OpenTimeout exception. The default value is 60 seconds.

**Read Timeout**

> Number of seconds to wait for one block to be read (via one read(2) call). Any number may be used, including Floats for fractional seconds. If the HTTP object cannot read data in this many seconds, it raises a Net::ReadTimeout exception. The default value is 60 seconds.

**URI Scheme**

Difference between generic uri (`URI::Generic`) and http uri (`URI::HTTP`).

```
 uri = URI.parse('1.1.1.1')
 => #<URI::Generic 1.1.1.1> 
 uri.scheme
 => nil 
 uri.host
 => nil 
 uri.port
 => nil 
 uri.path
 => "1.1.1.1" 

 uri = URI.parse('http://1.1.1.1')
 => #<URI::HTTP http://1.1.1.1> 
 uri.scheme
 => "http" 
 uri.host
 => "1.1.1.1" 
 uri.port
 => 80 
 uri.path
 => ""
```

references:

- [`Net::HTTP` Api](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html)
- [`URI` Module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html)

hope it helps!

#### UPDATE

[`URI.parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Parser.html#method-i-parse) accepts a string as argument and automatically set the port if not specified:

```
❯ irb
2.2.0 :001 > require 'net/http'
 => true 
2.2.0 :002 > uri = URI.parse('http://1.1.1.1')
 => #<URI::HTTP http://1.1.1.1> 
2.2.0 :003 > uri.host
 => "1.1.1.1" 
2.2.0 :004 > uri.port
 => 80 
2.2.0 :005 > uri2 = URI.parse('http://mydomain')
 => #<URI::HTTP http://mydomain> 
2.2.0 :006 > uri2.host
 => "mydomain" 
2.2.0 :007 > uri2.port
 => 80 
2.2.0 :008 > uri3 = URI.parse('https://mydomain')
 => #<URI::HTTPS https://mydomain> 
2.2.0 :009 > uri3.host
 => "mydomain" 
2.2.0 :010 > uri3.port
 => 443
```

Comment: That makes sense but quick question: if I have https://IP or http://ip in my list would that still work? Or should I just change it IP and assign it a uri.port value ?

Comment: I get an error for URI::InvalidURIError with or without the http(s) behind the IP for an IP like 1.1.1.1 (not a real IP)

Comment: @user3610137I update my answer to respond to your question. You don't need to specify a port with `URI.parse` method, but it needs `http://` or `https://` before the address.
Really strange your errror `URI::InvalidURIError`, Do you have pass the address to `URI.parse` as a string?

Comment: @user3610137 did you solve the problem? I was not able to reproduce your errors, did you look the update of the answer?

Comment: I'm still getting the following with just 1.1.1.1 when I run your 2nd code snippet : ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:66:in `split': bad URI(is not URI?): {:http=>//} (URI::InvalidURIError)

Comment: @user3610137 mmh strange. From the error message it seems you are not passing `1.1.1.1`, but `//` as address to URI. See this line of code https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_2/lib/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb#L66

Could you share the file with addresses or part of these? Maybe is a problem of encoding or similar.

Comment: @user3610137 I was able to reproduce your problem :) you need to encode the uri. I've just update the answer (the 2nd snippet), let me know if it works for you

Comment: Is "execution expired" being thrown out if it's unresponsive?

Comment: ah I see. That's from `    rescue Timeout::Error, URI::Error, SocketError => e
      puts e`